# Polymer 1.0 observers - not working on array

Tags: arrays, polymer, push, observers

I set an observer on to catch all polymer recognized events on an property that is an array, but I catch get it to catch the change.  In my example below my observer function "bigup" only gets called on when the property, "bigs" is first initialzed.

```
<dom-module id="parent-page">
<template>
    <paper-button on-click="updateAll">Update</paper-button>
</template>
<script>
    var temp=[];
    temp.push({'conversation':[{'message':'hello'}]});

    Polymer({
        is: 'parent-page',
        properties: {
            bigs: {
                type: Array,
                value: temp
            }
        },
        observers: [
            'bigup(bigs.*)'
        ],
        updateAll: function(){
            this.bigs.push({'conversation':[{'message':'hola'}]});
            console.dir(this.bigs);
        },
        bigup: function(){
            console.log('big Up');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I also tried to use bigs.push in the observer but had no success.  One part I don't understand is that if I add the following line to my "updateAll" function, the observer catches the change and fires "bigup".

```
this.bigs=[];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `push` method from Polymer instead of doing `this.bigs.push`.

So replace that line of code with

```
this.push('bigs', {'conversation':[{'message':'hola'}]});
```

For more info have a look at this [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html).

Comment: is there a way to use Polymer's push on a sub array of a property?

Comment: Try `this.push('bigs.0', {'conversation':[{'message':'hola'}]});`, assuming the first property is the subarray.

Answer (score 6):

For me [this article](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation) was helpful as well, it covers both the way to register the observer as well as the splices methods as suggested by Justin XL.

**Registering** the observer:

```
properties: {
    users: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        return [];
      }
    }
  },

  observers: [
    'usersAddedOrRemoved(users.splices)'
  ],
```

**Calling** splices methods the Polymer 1.0 way:

```
this.push('users', 'TestUser');
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation

**FYI - this will NOT work in all cases (my initial idea)**
When you register the observer in the property declaration like this:

```
 properties: {
        users: {
          type: Array,
          value: function() {
            return [];
          },
          observer: 'usersAddedOrRemoved'
        }
      },
```

In this case the `usersAddedOrRemoved` method is only called when you assign a new array to the users object. It will not however fire when you mutate the array by pushing, popping, splicing etc.