# How to append data to a polymer google-chart?

Tags: google-visualization, polymer

Take a look at this google-chart:

```
<google-chart id='c1' type='line' options='{"title": "Example"}'></google-chart>
```

To fill it with data I can do:

```
document.getElementById("c1").data = [["Date", "Value"], ["01.01.2016", 100]];
```

However, I am not able to append data, this does not work:

```
document.getElementById("c1").data.push(["02.01.2016", 200]);
```

How can I push/splice data to/from it?

I want to push a value by WebSocket regularly and remove the oldest one in the same time.

**Update 1**

I have tried replacing the `data` with `rows` and `cols`.

`rows` is a plain array, you can just `push` data to it, which works, partly.

In fact, before the chart is drawn, you can use `document.getElementById("xy").rows.push();` and it works (That is, once the chart is drawn, it includes the pushed rows.

But, after the chart has been drawn, `push` does not work anymore. The update to `rows` is silently swallowed and results in no update of the chart.

Note that calling `document.getElementById("c1").drawChart();` also does not update the chart's view.

**Update 2**

As suggested by @Ümit I have tried the following two, unfortunately both without success:

```
    var chart = document.getElementById("c1");
    chart.data = [["Year", "Things", "Stuff"], ["2004", 1000, 400], ["2005", 1170, 460], ["2006", 660, 1120], ["2007", 1030, 540]];
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        chart.push('data',["2008", 200, 999]);
        chart.drawChart();
        console.log("Pushed");
    }, 1000);

    var chart = document.getElementById("c1");
    chart.cols = [{label: "Category", type: "string"}, {label: "Value", type: "number"}];
    chart.rows = [["Category 1", Math.random() * 2], ["Category 2", Math.random() * 2]];
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        chart.push('rows', ["Category 3", Math.random() * 2]);
        chart.drawChart();
        console.log("Pushed");
    }, 1000);
```

**Update 3**

Third try, replacing the complete `rows`, without success:

```
    var chart = document.getElementById("c1");
    chart.cols = [{label: "Category", type: "string"}, {label: "Value", type: "number"}];
    chart.rows = [["Category 1", Math.random() * 2], ["Category 2", Math.random() * 2]];

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var temp = chart.rows;
        //console.log(temp);
        temp.push(["Category 3", Math.random() * 2]);
        //console.log(temp);
        chart.push('rows', temp); // does not work
        chart.rows = temp;        // does also not work
        chart.drawChart();
        console.log("Pushed");
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution:

```
    var chart = document.getElementById("c1");
    chart.data = [["Year", "Things", "Stuff"], ["2004", 1000, 400], ["2005", 1170, 460], ["2006", 660, 1120], ["2007", 1030, 540]];

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var temp = [["Year", "Things", "Stuff"], ["2004", 1000, 400], ["2005", 1170, 460], ["2006", 660, 1120], ["2007", 1030, 540], ["2008", 200, 999]];
        //chart.push("data", temp); // does not work
        chart.data = temp;          // works
        //chart.drawChart();        // is not necessary
        console.log("Pushed");
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dealing with `Arrays` and `Objects` respectively you need to use the [array/object mutation functions](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#array-mutation) of Polymer to ensure that the observer in `google-chart` is called and the chart gets updated.

So in your code you should do this:

```
document.getElementById("c1").push('data',["02.01.2016", 200]);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("xy").push('row',["02.01.2016", 200]);
```

**Update**:

The problem is that `google-chart` relies on normal [property observers](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/blob/master/google-chart.html#L286) for `data`, `rows` and `cols` which will only work if you replace the entire array/object (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33134172/356594) SO answer).

So either you can create an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues) in the `google-chart` repo or re-create `data`/`rows`

Comment: I've tried both, unsuccessfully :-( I've updated the question.

Comment: Ok I will try to debug it locally

Comment: I tried replacing rows, without success... see my updated answer (in 1 minute)